# WordPress Dashboard Not Coming Up

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

A bit of newbie to WordPress.  Had an issue with WordPress. Deleted WordPress and reinstalled it.  Funny thing is, it still gives me the sites name "Test".  Now, I do not see the dashboard.  The only plugin I had, was askimet and I renamed that.  Tried clearing cache.  Tried setting wp-config to "True" and do not see an error.log or error_log in the wordpress directory.

https://screenshots.firefox.com/ETYJU3ho4EGjqPr5/localhost

Comment: How exactly did you go about deleting WordPress?

Comment: What about https://<server>/wp-admin? Does it load dashboard fine?

Comment: i removed the parent directory and all sub-directories.

Comment: https://<server>/wp-admin -- didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a delete only on the Wordpress files and not on the database that is why you will see your "Test" site again since you are using same database.

Try to open

```
site-url/admin
```

and see if you will get **login form**.  You need to login as **admin** if you need to access the dashboard

Comment: i do that and login as the admin.  there is only one user/admin.  but, i don't get the dashboard.

Comment: i didn't delete the database, that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which worked, but I did two things.
1. Deleted and recreated the wordpress database.
2. There is a /var/www/html/wp-config.php  I was trying to update the wp-config.php file in the wordpress directory.  Apparently, the /var/ww/html/wp-config.php is the one that needs to be set for db, user, password, etc.

Just deleting the database was not enough.  Because I deleted the database and reinstalled wordpress, without success.  Then, I changed the variables in the /var/ww/html/wp-config.php file and the install worked.

Answer (score 0):

wp-config.php is the correction that did the job.
Not only user,password and database info.
Table prefix entry in wp-config.php should match the database table prefix as well